# Why do I need to localize $@ before using eval?

Tags: perl, exception, eval, die

I'm aware of the fact that `$@` is a global variable, still I can't figure out why I need to localize it before using [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

For instance:

```
eval { SOME_FUNC_THAT_MAY_DIE(); };
if ($@) {
  print "An error occured!\n";
}
```

The only possible thing I can think of is, if some signal handler will call `die` at the same time I try to read `$@`, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason to say `local $@` before calling `eval` is to avoid stepping on your caller's `$@`.  It's rude for a subroutine to alter any global variables (unless that's one of the stated purposes of the subroutine).  This isn't really an issue with top-level code (not inside any subroutine).

Also, on older Perl's, any `eval` called during object destruction would clobber the global `$@` (if the object was being destroyed because an exception was being thrown from an `eval` block) unless `$@` was localized first.  This was [fixed in 5.14.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Exception-Handling), but many people are still running older Perls.

Answer (score 9):

The [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny) module documentation gives the rationale (as well as providing an alternative):

> When you run an eval block and it succeeds, $@ will be cleared, potentially clobbering an error that is currently being caught.
>
> This causes action at a distance, clearing previous errors your caller may have not yet handled.
>
> $@ must be properly localized before invoking eval in order to avoid this issue.
>
> More specifically, $@ is clobbered at the beginning of the eval, which also makes it impossible to capture the previous error before you die (for instance when making exception objects with error stacks).

Comment: The reason I found this post, was exactly because I didn't understand exactly this paragraph in Try::Tiny's documentation. What does `potentially clobbering an error that is currently being caught` mean? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, but if you wrote code like this, localizing $@ would keep the first error as it was. and if you didn't write code like this, the local $@ would have no effect. better would be to handle errors before running any extra code.

```
eval {
    die "error 1\n";
};
foo();
print "processing $@\n";

sub foo {
    #local $@;
    eval {
        die "error 2\n";
    };
}
```